# Lync client state invalid

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2010

When using the Lync 2010 API the LyncClient can get in the `Invalid` state. This occurs if for instance the Lync process is shut down.
When Lync is started again a call to `Lync.GetClient()` returns a Lync client reference in an `Invalid` state. 
Reading the MSDN documentation is not very useful - the `Invalid` state is not described: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.model.clientstate_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt.aspx

My question is; how can I retrieve a Lync client reference which is not in an `Invalid` state?

Thanks!

Comment: Strange - I don't get this behaviour. I can call GetClient(), check the state, shut down Lync OR kill the process, start Lync and then call GetClient() again - and it returns the correct status. Are you using Lync in UI suppression mode, or automation mode? maybe you could post some code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I think this is happening when the GetClient() method is called from another thread then the one originally calling the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to my question/problem is to call the `GetClient()` from the same thread as it is called from the first time. This seems to never get a client in the `Invalid` state.

Answer (score 0):

After numerous tries, I reached a not-so-pretty workaround:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Lync.Model;
using ContactAvailability = Microsoft.Lync.Controls.ContactAvailability;

namespace LyncService
{
    public class MicrosoftLyncService : IMicrosoftLyncService
    {
        private readonly string _password = "1234";
        private readonly object _syncObj = new object();
        private readonly string _username = "Joe@YourCompany.com";
        private volatile LyncClient _lyncClient;

        public SkypeContactInfoViewModel GetSkypeContactInfo(string emailAddress)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (_syncObj)
                {
                    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = "taskkill",
                        Arguments = "/im lync.exe /f /t",
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false
                    })?.WaitForExit();

                    _lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient(true);

                    if (_lyncClient.State == ClientState.Uninitialized)
                    {
                        _lyncClient.BeginInitialize(ar =>
                            {
                                _lyncClient.EndInitialize(ar);
                                _lyncClient.StateChanged += ClientStateChanged;
                            },
                            null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _lyncClient.StateChanged += ClientStateChanged;
                        SignIn(_username, _username, _password);
                    }

                    while (_lyncClient.State != ClientState.SignedIn)
                        switch (_lyncClient.State)
                        {
                            case ClientState.Invalid:
                                _lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient(true);
                                Thread.Sleep(100);
                                break;
                            case ClientState.Uninitialized:
                                _lyncClient.BeginInitialize(ar =>
                                {
                                    _lyncClient.EndInitialize(ar);
                                    _lyncClient.StateChanged += ClientStateChanged;
                                },
                                null);
                                break;
                            case ClientState.SigningIn:
                                Thread.Sleep(100);
                                break;
                            case ClientState.SignedOut:
                                SignIn(_username, _username, _password);
                                Thread.Sleep(100);
                                break;
                        }

                    var contact = _lyncClient.ContactManager.GetContactByUri(emailAddress);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    var contactInfo = contact.GetContactInformation(new List<ContactInformationType>
                    {
                        ContactInformationType.Availability,
                        ContactInformationType.ContactEndpoints,
                        ContactInformationType.Title,
                        ContactInformationType.Company,
                        ContactInformationType.Department
                    });

                    return ConvertToSkypeViewModel(emailAddress, contactInfo);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Handle exception
            }
        }

        private SkypeContactInfoViewModel ConvertToSkypeViewModel(string emailAddress,
            IDictionary<ContactInformationType, object> contactInfo)
        {
            var result = new SkypeContactInfoViewModel();
            if (contactInfo.TryGetValue(ContactInformationType.Availability, out var availability))
                result.AvailabilityStatus = (ContactAvailability) availability switch
                {
                    ContactAvailability.Invalid => Enums.ContactAvailabilityStatus.Invalid,
                    ContactAvailability.None => Enums.ContactAvailabilityStatus.None,
                    ContactAvailability.Free => Enums.ContactAvailabilityStatus.Free,
                    ContactAvailability.FreeIdle => Enums.ContactAvailabilityStatus.FreeIdle,
                    ContactAvailability.Busy => Enums.ContactAvailabilityStatus.Busy,
                    ContactAvailability.BusyIdle => Enums.ContactAvailabilityStatus.BusyIdle,
                    ContactAvailability.DoNotDisturb => Enums.ContactAvailabilityStatus.DoNotDisturb,
                    ContactAvailability.TemporarilyAway => Enums.ContactAvailabilityStatus.TemporarilyAway,
                    ContactAvailability.Away => Enums.ContactAvailabilityStatus.Away,
                    ContactAvailability.Offline => Enums.ContactAvailabilityStatus.Offline,
                    _ => Enums.ContactAvailabilityStatus.Invalid
                };
            if (contactInfo.TryGetValue(ContactInformationType.ContactEndpoints, out var endPoints))
                ((List<object>) endPoints).ForEach(endPointObject =>
                {
                    if (endPointObject is ContactEndpoint endPoint && endPoint.Type == ContactEndpointType.WorkPhone)
                        result.WorkPhone = endPoint.DisplayName;
                });
            if (contactInfo.TryGetValue(ContactInformationType.Title, out var title)) result.JobTitle = (string) title;
            if (contactInfo.TryGetValue(ContactInformationType.Company, out var company))
                result.CompanyName = (string) company;
            if (contactInfo.TryGetValue(ContactInformationType.Department, out var department))
                result.Department = (string) department;

            return result;
        }

        private void ClientStateChanged(object source, ClientStateChangedEventArgs data)
        {
            if (data.NewState != ClientState.SignedOut) return;
            if (_lyncClient.InSuppressedMode)
                SignIn(_username, _username, _password);
        }

        public void SignIn(string userUri, string domain, string password)
        {
            _lyncClient.CredentialRequested += CredentialRequested;
            if (_lyncClient.State == ClientState.SignedOut)
                _lyncClient.BeginSignIn(
                    userUri,
                    domain,
                    password,
                    callback => { _lyncClient.EndSignIn(callback); },
                    null);
        }

        private void CredentialRequested(object sender, CredentialRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == CredentialRequestedType.SignIn)
                e.Submit(_username, _password, true);
        }
    }
}
```